# Maybe incorrect "Possible 'System.NullReferenceException'" tip in Resharper

Tags: c#, resources, resharper

I want to iterate a list and get label text values. Everything works fine apparently, expect by Resharper tip. The code:

```
string someString = GetLocalResourceObject(GetNameAsResource(resourceKey)) != null ?
                GetLocalResourceObject(GetNameAsResource(resourceKey)).ToString() :
                parametro.Parametro.Nome;
```

And in `GetLocalResourceObject(GetNameAsResource(resourceKey)).ToString()` Resharper suggest: Possible 'System.NullReferenceException'
I'm doing something wrong or Resharper just not recognize the previous null verification?

Tks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `GetLocalResourceObject()` is a *method*, ReSharper doesn't know that the return value from the second invocation is going to be the same as the return value from the first invocation! Do this:

```
var resourceObject = GetLocalResourceObject(GetNameAsResource(resourceKey));
string someString = 
    resourceObject != null 
    ? resourceObject.ToString() 
    : parametro.Parametro.Nome;
```

and the warning will go away, because now ReSharper knows that `resourceObject` has been checked for nullity before having a method invoked on it.

It might be better to look into the [Null Object Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern) - that is, in the case where `GetLocalResourceObject` currently returns `null`, have it instead return an actual object that represents 'no resource'. Then you wouldn't need this nullity check at all.

Comment: A GetLocalResourceObjectOrDefault method seems to be more natural in .NET.